# How to improve my code to correctly count unique lines?

Tags: c++

I am currently trying to write code for finding unique lines as well as unique words. I have my attempted code below for unique lines but it is not calculating correctly when it comes to unique lines. I believe it is ignoring enters and still counting lines that contain letters, words, sentences, etc. So I need help in figuring out what to add that it will count enters (blank lines) as lines and not count any extra lines that are the same. I know this is happening because I have tested a few different lines. As for the unique words, I don't even know how to get started :/

```
unsigned long countULines(const string& s)
{
   set<string> wl;
   string ulines;
   for(int ul = 0; ul < s.size(); ul++){
      wl.insert(ulines);
   }
   return wl.size();
}
```

Comment: `ulines` is never modified inside the loop. The entire loop is basically a no-op after the first insertion.

Comment: You need to stick `s` in a `stringstream` and use `getline` on it.

Comment: If it doesn't contain multiple lines, the whole function is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <set>

size_t countUniqueLines(const std::string& s)
{
    std::set<std::string> uniqueLines;
    std::istringstream is(s);

    std::string line;
    while (std::getline(is, line)) {
        if (!line.empty() && line[line.size() - 1] == '\r') {       
          line.erase(line.size() -1);
        }
        uniqueLines.insert(line);
    }

    return uniqueLines.size();
}

int main()
{
    const std::string myLines = "four\none\n\ntwo\nthree\nthree\n\n";

    std::cout << countUniqueLines(myLines) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it is better but I think it isn't counting blank lines still.

Comment: Certainly is here. The unique line count for the example string is 5. "four\n" (1), "one\n" (1), "\n" (2), 1 "two\n", (2) "three\n" (1) == 7 lines total, 5 unique. 2 of which are blank lines counted as a single unique line.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. The two text files I'm testing doesn't give me the right answers. One of them is "this is a test\n this is another test\n this is the same line\n this is the same line" It is giving me 4 when the answer should be 3.

Comment: I am getting the errors: 'std::string' has no member named 'back' and same goes for 'pop_back' So, not using C++11

Comment: Sorry I use C++11 by default now ;) Fixed.

Comment: I've tested my text files on a different compiler and it seems to work fine. The other one I was using still gives me wrong answer :/ Thanks though for helping me so much =D.